# RailsでモデルのインスタンスからURLのパスを取得するときに、その取得するURLを変更する方法

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

例えば、Railsの`scaffold`で、Viewなどを作成した場合、次のようなコードが生成されるかと思われます。フォーム画面だったりすると:

```
<%= form_for(@foobar) do |f| %>
....
<% end %>
```

であったり、あるいは

```
<%= link_to 'Show', @foobar %>
```

といったように。このテンプレートから、恐らく何らかの形で、モデルからパスを取得できるものである、っと推測が出来るように感じます。

しかし、この`Foobar`モデルが、`HogeHoge`モデルと関連するようになったため、当初URL構造を`/foobar/:id`から、`/hogehoge/:id/foobar/:id`といったURLにしたとします。

このとき、`@foobar`からアクセスすると、以前のまま`/foobar/:id`を生成してしまいます。仕方ないので、下のようにリンクを渡したりしています:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', hogehoge_foobar_path(:hogehoge_id => @hogehoge.id, :id => @foobar.id) %>
```

しかし、これはどう考えてもバットノウハウのように感じます。本来ならば、モデルインスタンスからURLを取得するほうが望ましいように感じます(要は`@foobar`から取得できるほうが望ましいように感じます)。

もし、モデルから取得されるURLを修正する方法について、何らかの参照するべきドキュメント、あるいは方法があれば教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlogモデルとEntryモデルがあり、Blogでは`has_many :entries`、Entryでは`belong_to :blog`という関係だとします。

`config/routes.rb` はこうします。

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :blogs do
    resources :entries
  end
end
```

ルーティングはこうなります

```
   blog_entries GET    /blogs/:blog_id/entries(.:format)          entries#index
                POST   /blogs/:blog_id/entries(.:format)          entries#create
 new_blog_entry GET    /blogs/:blog_id/entries/new(.:format)      entries#new
edit_blog_entry GET    /blogs/:blog_id/entries/:id/edit(.:format) entries#edit
     blog_entry GET    /blogs/:blog_id/entries/:id(.:format)      entries#show
                PATCH  /blogs/:blog_id/entries/:id(.:format)      entries#update
                PUT    /blogs/:blog_id/entries/:id(.:format)      entries#update
                DELETE /blogs/:blog_id/entries/:id(.:format)      entries#destroy
```

`link_to`メソッドはこんな風に呼び出すことになります。index.html.erbから抜粋しました。`@blog`はコントローラで`@blog=Blog.find(params[:blog_id])`しときましょう。

```
<%= link_to 'Show', [@blog, entry] %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_entry_path(@blog, entry) %>
<%= link_to 'Destroy', [@blog, entry], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<%= link_to 'New Entry', new_blog_entry_path(@blog) %>
```

`form_for`でも同じようにできます.

```
<%= form_for([@blog, @entry]) do |f| %>
```

詳しいことは"Nested Resource"をキーにしてドキュメントなどを読んでみてください